# Is Skolem arithmetic effectively axiomatizable?

Tags: logic, model-theory

[Skolem arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_arithmetic)

I found nothing via Google about its 
axioms. Wikipedia says nothing about whether it has ever been effectively axiomatized. If it has, then what do its effective axioms look like?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "multiplicatively axiomatizable". The set of all sentences true in the structure $(\mathbb{N},\times)$ is an axiomatization in the language $\{\times\}$. A better question would be: "What is an *explicit* axiomatization of Skolem arithmetic"? Which probably can be best answered by reading the reference for Wikipedia's claim that this theory is decidable.

Answer (score 4):

In my initial comment to the OP, I wrote:

> A better question would be: "What is an explicit axiomatization of Skolem arithmetic"? Which probably can be best answered by reading the reference for Wikipedia's claim that this theory is decidable.

I finally took my own advice on this. Wikipedia's reference is to *A Survey of Arithmetical Definability* by Bès. Here one can read that Skolem arithmetic was axiomatized by Cegielski in the paper [Theorie elementaire de la multiplication des entiers naturels](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0095657). One can find a summary of Cegielski's results in (in English) in Chapter III.5 of [Logical Number Theory I](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540522362) by Smorynski. I'll give a further summary of what I read in Smorynski's book here.

Let's agree to axiomatize the complete theory of $(\mathbb{N}_+,\cdot)$ here (where $\mathbb{N}_+ = \mathbb{N}\setminus 0$). If you want to include $0$, it's easy to obtain an axiomatization of $(\mathbb{N},\cdot)$ from this by asserting the existence of $0$ ($\exists x \forall  y (xy = x\land yx = x)$) noting it must be unique, and then restricting all the quantifiers in the axioms below to the non-zero elements.

Let's introduce some abbreviations:

- $x|y$ is an abbreviation for $\exists z(xz = y)$. It means "$x$ divides $y$".
- $x|_n y$ is an abbreviation for $\exists z(xz^n = y)$. It means "$x$ divides $y$  and the quotient is an $n^{\text{th}}$ power". We say "$x$ $n$-divides $y$". Note $0$-dividing is equality and $1$-dividing is ordinary dividing.
- $O(x)$ is an abbreviation for $\forall y\, (xy = y)$. It means "$x = 1$".
- $P(x)$ is an abbreviation for $\lnot O(x)\land \forall  y(y|x\rightarrow (O(y)\lor y = x))$. It means "$x$ is prime".
- $PP(x,y)$ is an abbreviation for $P(x)\land x|y\land \forall z((P(z)\land z\neq x\rightarrow \lnot (z|y))$. It means "$x$ is prime and $y$ is a power of $x$".
- $V(x,y,z)$ is an abbreviation for $PP(x,z)\land z|y \land \forall w((PP(x,w)\land w|y)\rightarrow w|z)$. It means "$z$ is the highest power of the prime $x$ which divides $y$".
- $T(x,y,z)$ is an abbreviation for $\forall p(P(p)\rightarrow ((p|x\rightarrow \exists w(V(p,y,w) \land V(p,z,w)))\land (\lnot p|x\rightarrow \lnot p|z)))$. It means "$z$ is the number obtained by deleting from the prime factorization of $y$ all primes not dividing $x$".
- $I(x,y)$ is an abbreviation for $\forall p(P(p)\rightarrow ((p|x\rightarrow \exists w(V(p,x,w)\land V(p,y,pw))\land (\lnot p|x\rightarrow \lnot p|y))$. It means "$y$ is the number obtained by increasing each prime exponent appearing in the prime factorization of $x$ by $1$".
- $S_n(p,x,y)$ is an abbreviation for $P(p)\land p|xy\land \exists z\exists w(V(p,x,z)\land V(p,y,w)\land z|_n w)$. It means "$p$ is a prime which divides $xy$, and the highest power of $p$ dividing $x$ $n$-divides the highest power of $p$ dividing $y$.
- For $n\geq 0$, $SP_n(x,y,z)$ is an abbreviation for $\forall p(P(p)\rightarrow ((S_n(p,x,y)\rightarrow V(p,z,p))\land (\lnot S_n(p,x,y)\rightarrow \lnot (p|z)))$. It means "$z$ is the product of those primes which divide $xy$ and for which the highest power of $p$ dividing $x$ $n$-divides the highest power of $p$ dividing $y$." You should think of this as a kind of comprehension/separation condition. If we think of an element as coding a (multi)set of primes (its prime factors), then $z$ codes the set of primes $p$ for which a certain modular arithmetic condition holds between the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorizations of $x$ and $y$.

Now we can give our axioms:

- $\forall x\forall y\forall z((xy)z = x(yz))$
- $\forall x\forall y(xy = yx)$
- $\exists x (O(x))$ [Note that uniqueness of $x$ follows from the previous axioms.]
- $\forall x\forall y\forall z(xz = yz\rightarrow x = y)$
- $\forall x\forall y(O(xy)\rightarrow (O(x)\lor O(y)))$
- $\forall x\forall y(x^n = y^n \rightarrow x = y)$ for each natural number $n>0$
- $\forall x\exists y\exists z(x = y^nz\land \forall y'\forall z'(x = (y')^nz'\rightarrow z|z'))$ for each natural number $n>0$
- $\forall x\exists p (P(p)\land \lnot  p|x)$
- $\forall x\forall y\forall z((PP(x,y)\land PP(x,z))\rightarrow (y|z\lor  z|y))$
- $\forall p\forall x(P(p)\rightarrow \exists y(V(p,x,y)))$ [Note that uniqueness of $y$ follows from the previous axioms.]
- $\forall x\forall y(x = y\leftrightarrow \forall p(P(p)\rightarrow \exists z(V(p,x,z)\land V(p,y,z))))$
- $\forall p\forall x\forall y(P(p)\rightarrow (\exists z\exists w (V(p,x,z)\land V(p,y,w)\land V(p,xy,zw))))$
- $\forall x\forall y(\forall  p(P(p)\rightarrow \exists z\exists w(V(p,x,z)\land V(p,y,w)\land z|w))\rightarrow x|y)$
- $\forall x\forall y\exists z(T(x,y,z))$ [Note that uniqueness of $z$ follows from the previous axioms.]
- $\forall x\exists y(I(x,y))$ [Note that uniqueness of $y$ follows from the previous axioms.]
- $\forall x\forall y\exists z(SP_n(x,y,z))$ for each natural number $n\geq 0$ [Note that uniqueness of $z$ follows from the previous axioms.]

Further, this theory has quantifier elimination in the definable expansion $\{\cdot,1,t,i,(sp_n)_{n\geq0},(E_n)_{n>0}\}$ where $1$ is a constant symbol defined by $O$ above, $t$ is a binary function symbol defined by $T(x,y,z)$ above, $i$ is a unary function symbol defined by $I(x,y)$ above,  $sp_n$ is a binary function symbol for each $n\geq 0$ defined by $SP_n(x,y,z)$ above, and $E_n(x)$ is a unary relation symbol for each $n>0$ defined by $$\exists p_1\dots\exists p_n(\bigwedge_{1\leq i < j \leq n} (p_i\neq p_j) \land \bigwedge_{1\leq i \leq n} (P(p_i)\land p_i|x)).$$

Disclaimer: I have not read Cegielski's proofs, only the summary of results in Smorynski. Some errors may have arisen in the "game of telephone" by which I summarized Smorynski's summary of Cegielski. But writing out the axiomatization here has given me some intuition for the kinds of complexities that arise in Skolem arithmetic - I hope it does the same for you!

Comment: This should be edited in to the Wikipedia page, at some point.

Answer (score 3):

It actually says on the page you linked

> **Skolem arithmetic** is the first-order theory of the natural numbers with multiplication, ...

So in notation this would be $(\mathbb{N}, \cdot)$ or $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{N}, \cdot)$. That is, our language consists of just the multiplication symbol (and equality of course, as always) and we take all the sentences in this language that are true in the natural numbers.

**Edit:** after the question was edited it now asks for an effective axiomatisation. As another answer already mentions, Skolem arithmetic is decidable (as can be found on the same Wikipedia page), so in particular it is effectively axiomatisable (i.e. the set of axioms is recursively enumerable).

Comment: So it doesn't have any axiom system composed of multiplicative axioms only, does it?

Comment: @Eli I believe I read somewhere that it is not finitely axiomatisable (can't dig up a reference now on my phone). There may be some other axiomatisation, but the question is if that gives an easier description.

Comment: Please notice that PA is not finitely axiomatizable either, nor is Presburger arithmetic, so why should I care about the infiniteness of the axioms of Skolem arithmetic? I'm only interested in the axioms themselves, whether finite or not.

Comment: @Eli what is a "multiplicative axiom"?

Comment: By multiplicative axiom I mean, an axiom using multiplication alone, e.g. the axiom: 0X=X.

Comment: @Eli Skolem arithmetic is a theory in the language $\{\times\}$, so an axiom for this theory cannot use any symbol other than $\times$ (and $=$ and the other primitive logical symbols like $\land$ and $\exists$). So (as I understand you) there's no distinction in this context between a "multiplicative axiom" and an "axiom". Also, I think you mean $0x = 0$...

Comment: Correct, but I had to make it clear, because a mathematician argued (while taliking to me) that this theory may use additive axioms - "outside of the theory", but contains multiplicative propostions only - "inside the theory", which is an arguement I couldn't accept.

Comment: The question is about **effective**, i.e., recursive axiomatizability, so your answer needs to give an argument that the theory of $(\Bbb{N}, \cdot)$ is r.e. (Aside: "axiomatizable" on its own is usually understood to mean recursively axiomatizable because without that restriction any theory would be axiomatizable for trivial reasons by the argument of your proposed answer.)

Comment: @RobArthan The question was edited, the original question was just asking about the axioms of Skolem arithmetic. It is also very common to study "the theory of <insert certain structure here>" in model theory.

Comment: Of course it's very common to study the theory of a particular structure or a class of structures, but then the question of axiomatizability is trivial if one accepts the entire theory as an axiomatization of itself. That's why "axiomatizable" is usually understood to mean recursively axiomatizable.

Comment: @MarkKamsma, I know Skolem arithmrtic is decidable, but I couldn't understand how all of that has anything to do with whether Skolem arithmetic is also effectively axiomatizable. There are contraexamples of theories being decidable yet not effectively axiomatizable, e.g. the set of all arithmetical propositions true in the set of finite natural numbers

Comment: @Eli Now I'm not sure what you mean by "effectively axiomatisable". Decidability implies that the set is recursively enumerable (see also the other answer). Also, I'm not sure what counterexample you mean. As I would interpret it is: "the set of all statements in the language of PA that are true in $\mathbb N$", but that is definitely not decidable.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Oh now I got it. I'd been confused by the ambiguity of the term "undecidabilty", which may also mean "neither provable nor disprovable", when referring to a statement rather than to a theory.

Answer (score 2):

The theory of $(\Bbb N, \times)$ is decidable (there is an algorithm that decides the truth value of a given formula in $\Bbb N$), so yes, Skolem arithmetic is effectively axiomatisable, because you can enumerate first-order formulas in the language $\times$ and keep the ones that are true in $\Bbb N$.
Sure, you will get a whole lot of redundant axioms but that still is an effective set of axioms.

Some examples (I omit the multiplication symbol because it would get cluttered) :

$\exists x\, \forall y \; xy=x$
$\exists x\, \forall y \; xy=y$
$\forall x\, \forall y \; xy=yx$
$\forall x\, \forall y \, \forall z\; x(yz)= (xy)z$
$\forall x\; ((\exists y \; xy \neq x) \implies \forall y\,\forall z \; (xy = xz \implies y=z))$
$\exists x\, \forall y \; x \neq yy$

Comment: Wow, very insrtuctive. Now I wonder if Skolem arithmetic is a sub-theory of PA.

Comment: @Eli I believe the answer is yes. In any model $N$ of PA, the multiplicative reduct $(N,\times)$ is a free commutative monoid on infinitely many generators (the primes of the model), together with $0$ (since PA proves the infinitude of primes and the uniqueness of prime factorization). And you can prove that any two such structures are elementarily equivalent using an Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé game argument. It follows that the multiplicative consequences of PA are already a complete first-order theory, which must coincide with Skolem arithmetic.

Comment: Incidentally, this gives a proof of the decidability of Skolem arithmetic: search for proofs from PA. It also might explain what the mathematician you were talking to meant by axioms "outside the theory" - you could define Skolem arithmetic to be the set of multiplicative consequences of the axioms of PA (of course, this doesn't mean it's right to view the axioms of PA as axioms of Skolem arithmetic).

Comment: So why only - "believe" - the answer is yes, rather than - simply - "yes"? Your argument seems to be sound and valid, doesn't it? Well, I've just noticed I too had used the phrase "seems to be", so the same question about you can now be asked about me....

Comment: @AlexKruckman if we state the axioms of a commutative monoid, and state an infinite family of axioms $(A_k)$ where $A_k$ says there are $k$ different prime numbers, is that theory complete or do we have to find a way to express the freeness of $\Bbb N$ ?

Comment: maybe with an induction schema $\phi(0) \land \phi(1) \land (\forall p, prime(p) \implies (\forall x, \phi(x) \implies \phi(px))) \implies \forall x \phi(x)$ for every formula $\phi(x)$

Comment: @Eli Haha - right, it's just that I hadn't fully checked the details. mercio: your induction schema just captures the idea that the prime elements generate, not that they generate freely.

Comment: Using Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé game argument, you seem to assume the set of generators (i.e. of primes) is countable, but if it's not - then how will this argument work?

Comment: @Eli Sorry, I just saw your last comment. Why would countability be relevant? Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé games apply to arbitrary structures. In case you're still interested in this question nearly two years later, I'm going to post an answer with an explicit axiomatization.